# Detect stateless charsets

Tags: java, character-encoding

Is there a way in Java to detect stateless charsets of all available charsets ([`Charset#availableCharsets()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#availableCharsets--))?

Stateless means that the given charset doesn't use shift-states for multiple Coded Character Sets, according to [this description](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/intro-i18n/ch-coding.en.html#s-stateful) (see 3.2 Stateless and Stateful).

I need this information because I'm currently developing a tool, that decodes binary streams at random positions and this is not possible using stateful charsets.

**Edit:** I noticed, when googling stateful encodings, that only ISO-2022 shows up. Are these the only stateful encodings available?
In this case the problem might be solved by distinguishing the encodings' stateness by name (i.e. all "ISO-2022"s are stateful / all others are not).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to know a `Charset` is stateful or not.

There are some stateful charsets other than ISO-2022 like:

- In the charset in [Java SE Supported Encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html), EUC (`EUC-JP`, `EUC-KR`, etc) has state explicitly. It uses single shifts to express its state. So for example you have to see a previous byte when you point an ASCII byte in the stream because ASCII bytes can appear as trail bytes. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code for details.
- Other than EUC, `Shift_JIS` and `Windows-31j` have state implicitly. For example, `0x83 0x84` means `ヤ`, and `0x84 0x83` means `с` in `Shift_JIS`. So when you get a byte array like `... 0x83 0x84 0x83 0x84 0x83 0x84 0x83 ...`, you have to backtrack to the start of the array to determine whether the array means `ヤヤヤヤヤ...` or `ссссс...`.
- Outside of Java SE Supported Encodings, some charsets used in Japanese mainframes (JIPS, KEIS, etc) are stateful. You have to treat them if your JDK supports such kinds of charsets.  See https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E3%82%B7%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89 for detail (Japanese).